# Is it possible to run node.js as service and pass parameters to it from any cmd?

Tags: node.js, service, background, arguments

I would like to run node.js server as a service so it would run without a need to keep cmd opened. User should be able to open command line any time and pass parameters to running server with custom command like `myapp --flag <param>`.

So the question is:
How can I pass arguments to a running background node.js service?

Comment: How about using PM2? It will load any node.js server in the background. and of course you can pass arguments using config file  http://pm2.keymetrics.io/

Comment: Can I pass them at any moment during server running?

Comment: you can add new arguments to config file and reload pm2. it will instantly restart the server. We are using PM2 on a very large project and we are very happy about it.